# How to find the coefficient of taylor series

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, residue-calculus

[image]

Why is the coefficient $21/8$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can get "$x^2$" multiplying those two sums is $(1)(z^2/4)$, $(1)(4z^2)$ (you have "4z" but, since you already have "2z", assume "$4z^2$" was what you intended), and $(2z)(z/2)$ so you have $z^2/4+ 4z^2+ z^2= (1/4+ 5)Z^2= 21/4$.  Since the entire expression is multiplied by $1/2$, you get $21/8$.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!